# Strange behaviour from C++ program with RF24 Radio Library and Interrupts on Raspi

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, arm, interrupt, radio-transmission

I've been running a script on my Raspi while incrementally improving its performance, it was working fine until I started editing it this morning, and now cout << will not print to the console but interestingly enough - radio.printDetails does print, which uses printf. I think maybe the SD card is starting to die? Could this cause the issue?

**Header:**

```
#include <bcm2835.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <RF24/RF24.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <time.h>

#define arrSize 50
//
// Hardware configuration
// Configure the appropriate pins for your connections

/****************** Raspberry Pi ***********************/

RF24 radio(RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_22, BCM2835_SPI_CS0);//, BCM2835_SPI_SPEED_4MHZ);
//RF24 radio(22,0); // CE GPIO, CSN SPI-BUS

int interruptPin = 23; // GPIO pin for interrupts
int i=0;
/**************************************************************/

// Radio pipe addresses for the 2 nodes to communicate.
//const uint8_t pipes[][6] = { 0xF0F0F0F0E1LL, 0xF0F0F0F0D2LL };
const uint8_t pipes[][6] = {"1Node","2Node"};

volatile int accelArryNo = 0;
volatile int currentArryNo = 0;
uint8_t ack = 30;
int liveAccelArray[arrSize*3];
float liveCurrentArray[arrSize];
const int max_receivePayload_size = 32;
volatile int recvd = 0;
uint8_t receivePayload[max_receivePayload_size]; // +1 to allow room for a terminating NULL char
uint8_t receivePayloadBuff[max_receivePayload_size];
bool role_ping_out = 1, role_pong_back = 0;
bool role = 0;

//mysql pointers
   MYSQL *conn;
   MYSQL_RES *res;
   MYSQL_ROW row;
```

main():

```
int main(){
   char *server = "localhost";
   char *user = "monitor";
   char *password = "monitor"; /* set me first */
   char *database = "data";
   conn = mysql_init(NULL);
   /* Connect to database */
   if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
         user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
      exit(1);
   }
   /* send SQL query */
   if (mysql_query(conn, "show tables")) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
      exit(1);
   }
   res = mysql_use_result(conn);

   /* output table name */
//   printf("MySQL Tables in mysql database:\n");
   while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
      //printf("%s \n", row[0]);

   mysql_free_result(res);

  // Setup and configure rf radio
  radio.begin();
  radio.setAutoAck(1);
  radio.enableDynamicPayloads();
  radio.enableAckPayload();
  radio.setRetries(0,15);
  radio.setDataRate(RF24_1MBPS);
  radio.printDetails();
  radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[1]);
  radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipes[0]);
  radio.writeAckPayload(1, &ack, sizeof(ack));
  if(radio.available()){
std::cout << "available";
    uint8_t len;
    len = radio.getDynamicPayloadSize();
    radio.read(&receivePayload, len);
  }
  std::cout << "listening";
  attachInterrupt(interruptPin, INT_EDGE_FALLING, intHandler); //Attach interrupt to bcm pin 23
  radio.startListening();


// forever loop
while(1){
if (recvd == 2){
    //addLiveData();
    recvd = 0;
} else if (recvd == 1) {
    insertData();
    recvd = 0;
}
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to finish your `cout` with `<< std::endl;` to flush the stream

Comment: std::cout is buffered, at least until a "\n", but it can be cached also more (you can use std::endl to flush it). If you want to print something consistently without a newline you should use std::cerr